# Tcl. Replace string in file

Tags: string, dictionary, replace, tcl

There is a command in tcl which allows to create new string on the basis of existing by replacement :

```
string map ?-nocase? mapping string
```

Whether there is in tcl a command allowing to change the existing string?
For example:

```
set string1 abcabcabc
```

By using some command replace a letter "a" by "0" to get string1 with value 0bc0bc0bc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @peter solution work perfectly well.

To replace `string` in file `TCL` without `fileutil` package:

```
set fd [open "filename.txt" r]
set newfd [open "filename.txt.tmp" w]
while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
    set newline [string map {a 0} $line]
    puts $newfd $newline
}

close $fd
close $newfd
file rename -force "filename.txt.tmp" "filename.txt"
```

Comment: Or `set f [open file.txt r+] ; puts -nonewline $f [string map {a 0} [read $f]][seek $f 0;list] ; close $f` ;) Works just as well, but I wouldn’t recommend it for production code.

Comment: @PeterLewerin “wouldn't recommend it for production code” — you can say that again! While it does fail-safe, it's easy to introduce a typo and make that untrue. OTOH, it _is_ worth considering the approach of transforming the whole contents of the file at once. Even for files of many megabytes, it's easy to work with things that way.

Answer (score 2):

```
% set string1 abcabcabc
abcabcabc
% set string1 [string map {a 0} $string1]
0bc0bc0bc
```

To replace in a file (the file "file.txt" contains `abcabcabc`):

```
% package require fileutil
% ::fileutil::updateInPlace file.txt {string map {a 0}}
% ::fileutil::cat file.txt
0bc0bc0bc
```

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)